# How to use RSA_PRIVATE_KEY in nodejs for JWT?

Tags: node.js, jwt

I'm following angular documentation https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/ in step 2 uses RSA_PRIVATE_KEY but it doesn't explain how to generate it, I have to install something to use

```
const RSA_PRIVATE_KEY = fs.readFileSync (' ./ demos / private.key ');?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need OpenSSL binary to generate the keys:

```
openssl genpkey -out private.pem -aes256 -algorithm rsa -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096
openssl pkey -in private.pem -out public.pem -pubout
```

You’re welcome ;)

Comment: Didn’t you check already? It doesn’t matter, you need openssl binary.

Comment: yes i checked but i got an error performing a request to the server  'error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
'

Comment: this is the error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59721820/evp-decryptfinal-exbad-decrypt-error-on-nodejs